# Correct method of setting CSS font-weight?

Tags: css, html

I am constructing a basic html5 website with 5 pages for practice as I am in the process of relearning html5 and CSS.

I have a div with ID "education" and Class "content-list". 
Inside this div is a Caption and an unordered list Class "content-ul"(NOTE: Caption is contained in "content-list"). The list contains 3 list items.

I want to set the font-weight to bold for the caption, but not the unordered list.

Here's what I have:

HTML:

```
HTML:
<div id="education" class="content-list">
<caption>Education:</caption>
<ul class="content-ul">
<li>Tafe</li>
<li>College</li>
<li>High School</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-list {
... styles
font-weight:bold; /* Sets caption and list to bold */
.... styles
}

.content-ul {
.... styles
font-weight:normal; /* Sets list back to normal */
.... styles
}
```

This achieves the desired result, but I am wondering if there is a better/more efficient way of doing this.

Keep in mind, 4 of the 5 pages use this code. For this reason I opted against using in line styles as I would have to do it 4 times in total. This would remove the need to set the list to bold and then back to normal again, but would still use more code than the chosen method.

Any help/suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`caption` is for tables, use i.e. a `h4` for lists

```html
<div id="education" class="content-list">
  <h4>Education:</h4>
  <ul class="content-ul">
    <li>Tafe</li>
    <li>College</li>
    <li>High School</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Side note, styling a caption work when used properly

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table caption {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Caption</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah ha! I knew I was doing something wrong. Even googling for answers I searched "table caption" yet I never clicked I didn't have a table, rather I have lists. Many thanks for your help and the useful displays.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through your example, I can see you only want `Education` to be bold and not the content other than it. For this simply, do it like

```
caption{
    font-weight:bold
}
```

CSS in OP won't be needed.

Comment: Strangely enough, anything I set to the caption element does not work. E. G. 'caption { font-weight:bold; color:red;}' results in normal weight text with the body text color assigned. Using the method I stated above is all that has worked so far.

Comment: Even creating a class for all the captions and styling it that way does not work...